# vim file specific .vimrc

Tags: vim

I want spell checking to be enabled on vim when editing .txt or .md files. I added

```
setlocal spell spelllang=en_au
```

to .vimrc but that did spell checking for everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be doable with an `autocmd` though I've never tried it:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.txt setlocal spell spelllang=en_au
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.md setlocal spell spelllang=en_au
```

Comment: Hey thanks that works, was hoping there would be a cleaner way to do it though.

Comment: Instead of separate lines, you can put the filespecs together on one.  I.e. `*.txt,*.md` or even `*.{txt,md}`  (I have about a dozen lines like this that each operate on ten filespecs, much easier to edit them all at once!)

Answer (score 1):

Well, try to enable spell check directly in vim, not ~/.vimrc

:set spell

Does it work?

spcific language spell check may not work in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted something that I could put in .vimrc instead of having to type in :set spell every time I edit a text or markdown file

Answer (score 1):

This would be what you need in _vimrc.

`set spell spelllang=en_us`